# For each Angular route I pull in a template. How do I enable the scopes and watches on those templates?

Tags: angularjs

I have an main page with ng-view defined.

My routing pulls in several templates.

```
config(['$locationProvider', '$routeProvider', function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');

    $routeProvider.when('/view1', {
        templateUrl: 'view1/view1.html',
      })

     .when('/view2', {
        templateUrl: 'view2/view2.html',
      })

    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/view1'});
}]);
```

My First template looks like this:

```
<p>This is the partial for view 1.</p>

<div ng-controller="View1Ctrl">

    <input  type="text" 
            ng-model="search" 
            ng-model-options="{ debounce: 800 }" 
            placeholder="Enter full movie name" 
            autofocus />

</div>
```

The JS for this template looks like this;

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', [])

.controller('View1Ctrl', [function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.$watch('search', function() {
      fetch();
    });

    function fetch(){
        alert("it werky");
    }

}]);
```

Why am I getting the error: angular.js:13708 TypeError: Cannot read property '$watch' of undefined?

I'm essentially pulling in a template with models and directives defined on it but I don't think those are being run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be your dependencies are not getting injected, you are passing an array with the constructor function as it's only element.

Here is a working plunk.http://plnkr.co/edit/U2hxQPBZMVo2jaR4bwsq?p=preview

```
myApp.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    alert ("jaiHo");
    $scope.$watch('search', function() {
        fetch();
    });

     function fetch(){
        alert("it werky");
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help!  I was missing the string injection part of the array and it was blowing the browsers mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.view1', [])

.controller('View1Ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.$watch('search', function() {
      fetch();
    });

    function fetch(){
        alert("it werky");
    }

}]);
```

Note how I inject dependencies

Comment: Yep this was it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('myApp.view1', [])
    .controller('View1Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        $scope.$watch('vm.search', function(newValue, oldValue) {
          fetch(newValue, oldValue);
        }, true);

        function fetch(newValue, oldValue){
          vm.newValue = newValue;
          vm.oldValue = oldValue;
        }
    });

}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp.view1">
  <div ng-controller="View1Ctrl as vm">
    <input ng-model="vm.search" type="text" />
    <div>
      Old Value: {{vm.oldValue}}
    </div>
    <div>
      New Value: {{vm.newValue}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```